# Android load resized image from asset

Tags: android, bitmap, resize, scale, assets

I am getting memory error in my android game and i think its caused by my image loading function. everything is working fine on my mobile but on tablet i get memory exceed error.

I am using a matrix because i need to resize the image to a float value. But in this case i have to load the image in full size first and then resize it with the matrix and i think this causes the memory error.

is this the correct way to handle image resize?

```
public class Sprite {
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;
    private float scaleX, scaleY;

    public Sprite(String path, float targetWidth, float targetHeight, Context context) {
        InputStream istr;
        AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        Matrix scalematrix = new Matrix();

        try {
            istr = assetManager.open(path);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
            scaleX = targetWidth / bitmap.getWidth();
            scaleY = targetHeight / bitmap.getHeight();
            scalematrix.postScale(scaleX, scaleY);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), scalematrix, true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BitmapFactory.Options has `public int inSampleSize` -- If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

You may try to use `BitmapFactory.decodeXXX(..., BitmapFactory.Options opts)` (decodeFile() etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i searched for the inSampleSize Option and the code from here helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825214/optimal-use-of-bitmapfactory-options-insamplesize-for-speed

Comment: if the problem is solved, you can accept the answer )